# This address received 94.502 monero, with 550 confirmation(s)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

> This address received 94.502 monero, with 550 confirmation(s).

Could you please help me understand what this means? It's been a while and the amount is still not received.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Tx ID:
56e5b0b467e55e137059de0278e2798153123b378d8c628bb5be47fce374f531
Payment ID:
0000000000000000
Tx key:
....99d871ec415268240e2b7eb7553cd064c7e4ffad6450b5e108dd20bad3107
Destinations:
94....501999760000: ...tWEBn5XZJSxLU6uLQnQ2iY9xuNcDbjLSjkn3XAXHCbLrTTErJrBWYgHJQyrCwkNgYvyV3z8zctJLPCZy24jvb3NiTcTJ

Comment: I have transferred to other address its been while but says.   This address received 94....502 monero, with 885 confirmation(s).

Comment: You're using testnet I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

This means that particular address received that amount of monero in the transaction you're looking at, and that this transaction was mined with that many blocks mined after it.

If you're not seeing this in your wallet, then you need to update your wallet to at least that block. This could be your wallet being out of date compared to your daemon, or your daemon being out of date compared to the network (or both). See questions about these things if that's the case.

Comment: The received address is bittres address.

Comment: I mean its bittrex address which I have sent...!

Comment: Then the "you need to update your wallet" changes to "they need to update their wallet". Just give it time, they may be busy partying now and might need a human to be back to manually fix stuff.

Comment: eventually what will happen if payment is not successful.?

Comment: Since the payment is mined with a lot of confirmations, it'd require a huge reorg for it to become unsuccessful again. Then, assuming it did not get mined again (unlikely) then it will get dropped off the txpool after a week. But this is not going to happen.

Comment: Here is the status so far.( This address received 94....502 monero, with 2782 confirmation(s).

Comment: Hi, There I can't see any result until today -  I have updated my wallet as well but can't see any balance neither bittrex address received any amount, any thoughts on this. please .?   ( This address received 94000....502 monero, with 7880 confirmation(s).

Comment: Use precise wording. You can't see any balance ? Do you mean you see an incorrect balance, or you really don't see any balance ?

Comment: I did this transaction on 2017-12-30 but still not confirmed when check payment status this is the notifications. ( This address received 940...502 monero, with 7880 confirmation(s). I mean still not confirmed or reversed to my wallet.

Comment: "7880 confirmation(s)" means confirmed. You previously said it was not to your wallet, but if it is, you need to make sure your monerod and monero-wallet-cli (or monero-wallet-gui) are synced to the right chain.

Comment: I have sent this amount from my Monero wallet gui - to Bittrex exchange address.But still not credited.